# Faster way to create crystal reports in VB .net?

Tags: vb.net

which is the faster way to create crystal reports in VB .net?

I just tried with FDF. Is there any fastest way to create crystal reports?

Answer (score 0):

I have created crystal reports using XSD. Its faster than FDF method.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. i will try try it.